# How to check if a string starts with ' " ' (double quotes)?

Tags: regex

Every time I write " my compiler assumes I am trying to write a String. Instead I want my method to tell me if the incoming string starts with a  double quote ""
Ex:

```
String n;
if(n==n.startsWith(" " " ));
```

doesn't work

Any suggestions??

Comment: Define : doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried `'"'` or `"\""` instead of `" " "` in your `startsWith` approach? the actual regex to match double quotes at the beginning of a string is `^"`, but each language has different notation for regex literals, most common would be `/^"/` I guess

Comment: Which language? Escape the double quotes with a backslash String n; if(n==n.startsWith(" \" " ));

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to escape double quotes in string!
If you do it like this: `" " "`, string ends on second quotation mark. If in Java, you code should be like:

```
String n;
if(n.startsWith("\""))
{
    // execute if true
}
```

Since you are matching just first character, you don't need to use such sophisticated tool as regular expressions:

```
String n;
if (n.charAt(0)=="\"")
{
    // execute if true
}
```

BUT. You should make sure if string is not empty. Just for safety:

```
String n;
    if (n.getText()!=null 
        && !n.getText().isEmpty() 
        && n.charAt(0)=="\"")
    {
        // execute if true
    }
```

PS: space is a character.

PSS: flagged as dublicate.

Comment: Java says == doesn't work for string and char

Comment: It doesn't work for string.. and any complex object. It can also cause problems with float type. Should be fine with char. I think ;)